# It's possibile to host a website on ec2 and connect it with an Aruba domain?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting

I often made websites, but I never had to host one. 
This time i've deployed a website written in nodejs and mongodb, but i have to host it. I've seen how to host this on an ec2 istance. Now the question is, if i buy a domain on Aruba is possibile to link it to ec2? And how I can do it? 
I've also seen that Aruba offer some differente domain packages. If it can be useful, Aruba offer this packages for domain. 
Domain with dns management, 
Domain with redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. If your instance is behind `ALB` or `CloudFront` - it's a bit more complicated, but propably (as it's your start with hosting sites) - you're using just ec2 instance.

You have to assign `ElasticIP` to your instance (to make it static), and then put this IP in `A` DNS record in your domain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes I use just ec2 instance. Can I assign ElasticIP using route53? Or I should use another service?

Comment: @sfale you can assign `ElasticIP` in EC2 -> ElasticIPs (you have to allocate one first)

Comment: Have you also some suggest about the hosting? Because I want to host an ecommerce and I'm not so sure about ec2 instance

Comment: @sfale it all depends. I'm working with e-commerce too, it's hosted on AWS but it's really complex architecture.

Comment: have you hosted the site on t2.micro? And for the database have you installed this on ec2 or have you used an external service for database

Comment: @sfale definietly not on t2.micro, it's too small for our usage :) for database we're using `AWS Aurora`